# Difference between Facebook graph and Koala rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, koala

I am using devise as a way to use authentication for login and logout. However I am confused on how to post on a friends wall about my application.

1- If I use devise and Omniauth this allow me to either sign with devise, or with facebook. But once login, all devise omniauth won't be able to post to facebook correct?

2- My understanding of koala and facebook graph, is I must have the user credentials, therefore I must use omniauth? Which mean all user login in with devise, won't be able to post to facebook?

3- If I login using simple devise, is there a way for me to ask for credentials, which then i can use to then post to their friends wall.

Any tutorial, or guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only correct way to login into Facebook is to use OAuth, regardless of framework or implementation. You cannot post to a wall only using credentials, you must use an OAuth Flow as described in Facebook Login documentation.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/